# How to sort Array of objects based on price?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would like to sort the IAP prices in the array.

This is the original unsorted array.

[image]

I'm sorting it this way: 
`options.sorted { $0.formattedPrice < $1.formattedPrice }`

It kind of works, but the £3.49 should be on top. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: But the better solution would be to have a *numeric* property and use that for sorting.

Comment: Just remove £ simbol from string when you create a comparator.